# Scope of variable i in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<script type= "text/javascript">

var i=10;
function f(){
   alert(i);
   if(!i){
     var i= 20;
   }
   alert(i);
}
f();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my html file.
The outputs I get are undefined for first alert and 20 for the second alert.
Why is this so? What is happening here?

Comment: You're creating private variable `var i = 20;` but previously you're alerting i so get undefined....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because the i is hoisted, but the assignment of i is not. Therefore, when you alert i,  it is referring to the locally scoped i which hasn't yet been assigned a value.

It ends up working like this:

```
var i;
alert(i);
if(!i){
    i = 20;
}
```

Comment: This is why in javascript you should declare function variables at the top because javascript doesn't have block scope.

Comment: oh so it is getting declared at top inside of function again?

Comment: your code ends up working like this:(see edited answer)

Comment: figured it out thanks